# AWS CloudSearch throws EndpointConnectionError exception

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to setup CloudSearch. At first I tried it with their demo dataset ("IMDB") and it all worked just perfect.

Then I created a new domain to export our data into it. But all the attempts to connect to the new domain result in an EndpointConnectionError exception. I tried it with and without indexes, upload and get documents, all with the same exception.

A simple code which reproduces the issue:

```
import boto3
cloudsearch = boto3.client('cloudsearch') # we store credentials in ~/.aws/
endpoint_url = cloudsearch.describe_domains(DomainNames=['DOMAINNAME',])['DomainStatusList'][0]['SearchService']['Endpoint']
cloudsearchdomain = boto3.client('cloudsearchdomain', endpoint_url='https://%s' % (endpoint_url,))

result = cloudsearchdomain.search(query='anything')
print result
```

This code was working great when `DOMAINNAME` was the domain with the IMDB demo dataset, but once I switched it to the new domain name it started throwing this exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://search-DOMAINNAME-bcoaescnsbrp2h5ojzyhljdc4u.us-west-2.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch?format=sdk"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the missing access policies. It seems like AWS auto-creates the policies for the domain when you create the demo dataset without notifying about it. So for the first domain access policies were created by AWS and I didn't know about that.